# Updating a specific csv column based on randomname

Tags: python, csv

My code pulls a random name from a csv file. When a button is pressed i want my code to search through the csv file, and update the cell next to the name generated previously in the code.

The variable in which the name is stored in is called `name`
The index which pulls the random name from the csv file is stored in the variable `y`

The function looks like this. I have asked this question previously however have had no luck in receiving answers, so i have made edits to the function and hopefully made it more clear.

```
    namelist_file = open('StudentNames&Questions.csv')
    reader = csv.reader(namelist_file)
    writer = csv.writer(namelist_file)
    rownum=0
    array=[]
    for row in reader:
        if row == name:
            writer.writerow([y], "hello")
```

[image: My csv file looks like this]

Only the first two columns of the csv file are relevant

This is the function which pulls a random name from the csv file.

```
def NameGenerator():
    namelist_file = open('StudentNames&Questions.csv')
    reader = csv.reader(namelist_file)
    rownum=0
    array=[]
    for row in reader:
        if row[0] != '':
            array.append(row[0])
            rownum=rownum+1
    length = len(array)-1
    i = random.randint(1,length)
    global name
    name = array[i]
    return name
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. Why are you trying to write `y` back to the CSV? What column should it go in?

Comment: It should go into the column next to the name generated. So if michael gets pulled and generated, the cell to the right of michael (on the csv) should increment by 1 becoming 6. I am only using y as it contains an index which i thought may be useful. I also thought the value (in this case y) between the square brackets [ ] was the location of the cell to be written to

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of issues with your code:

1. You're trying to have both a reader object and a writer on the same file at the same time. Instead, you should read the file contents in, make any changes necessary and then write the whole file back out at the end.
2. You need to open the file in write mode in order to actually make changes to the contents. Currently, you don't specify what mode you're using so it defaults to read mode.
3. `row` is actually a list representing all data in the row. Therefore, it cannot be equal to the name you're searching, only the 0th index might be.

The following should work:

```
with open('StudentNames&Questions.csv', 'r') as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile)
    data = [row for row in reader]

for row in data:
    if row[0] == name:
        row[1] += 1

with open('StudentNames&Questions.csv', 'w', newline='') as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    writer.writerows(data)
```

Comment: Im receiving an error with this - line 6 - 'cant convert int to str implicitly'

Comment: @CallumTwig Where is `name` defined and what do you get from `print(type(name))`?

Comment: I have updated my post to show where name is defined.

Comment: name is defined as a string - program returned <class 'str'>. I think the issue lies with the data type for the scores column (index 1) of the csv file

Comment: @CallumTwig the screenshot suggests that it is numerical. You can try `row[1] = str(int(row[1]) + 1)`

Comment: Perfect. Any chance you could create a separate script for turning every value in column index 1 to 0?

Comment: @CallumTwig you already have the component parts you need. I've shown you how to read the data in, modify a value in a particular column and write it back out. The only thing you need to do is set the value to 0 instead of adding to it.

Comment: Isnt that going to give me the same error as before though?

Comment: @CallumTwig Why would it? You're not trying to add anything now, you're just asking to set the value yourself. And even if it does, I fixed that issue too in the comments.

Comment: Ive set it to just 0 and it doesnt work? I'm sorry for using more off your time im just coding in unfamiliar territory.

Comment: @CallumTwig `for row in data: row[1] = 0`